# Why do global inline variables and static inline members in C++17 need guards?

Tags: c++, c++17, inline

Since C++17 it's possible to initialize global variables and static members in headers using the `inline` keyword. While I understand why static variables in functions need to be guarded (because initialization should happen only once even in a multithreaded context), I don't get why these new inline variables are also guarded (you can see it here: https://godbolt.org/z/YF8PeQ). I thought that in any case initialization of all globals and static members happens at the beginning of program execution (even before `main()`), so there's no need to think about multiple threads at this moment. Can you explain it, please?

Answer (score 25):

Every file that contains the definition and uses it will try to initialize the variable. Even if that happens serially, not concurrently, you still need a way to mark the variable as initialized, so that only  the first ocurrence will initialize it and later attempts to initialize it won't do anything.

Also, you can have multiple threads before `main` starts. Constructors of global variables (and functions called by those constructors) can spawn new threads.

So you can have multiple pieces of code, all executing before `main`, all trying to initialize the same variable. That's what the guards are for.

Comment: What do you mean by "file will try to initialize"? I thought the fact of initialization should be resolved by linker, and I don't really see why linker can't "combine" all initializations of global variable/static member in different object files into one (like he does with inline global function definitions in header) and put it in the right place in the assembly.
And how code in these threads can possibly initialize something except variable which constructor spawned thread of? It can access another global (initialized or not, depends on order), but it can't influence its initialization.

Comment: The linker cannot run constructors for global variables that require non-trivial initialization, that has to happen at runtime, after the program starts executing (but before `main` starts).

Comment: A global constructor can create a thread, which can call a function defined in a different object file, which can trigger initialization of globals defined in that file. C++ initialization is a lot more complicated than I think you realize.

Comment: @JohnLettehw - Additionally, a thread running before `main()` starts can change the value of a global variable. A constructor that runs before `main()` can read the value of a global variable. Therefor, whether or not the thread does this before the constructor runs is important.