# Does C++17 "static inline" solve the static initialization order fiasco?

Tags: c++, static, initialization, c++17

I have occasionally encountered the "C++ static initialization order fiasco", in which some complex global object (such as a hash table) is used by another class before it has been constructed, sometimes resulting in crashes during initialization before main() is entered.

As is well-known, this fiasco can be avoided by embedding the parts of an object requiring initialization as a static in a member function, because a static in a function is always initialized the first time the function is entered, for example:

```
struct GlobalHashTable
{
   std::map <std::string, int>& stringmap()
   {
       static std::map <std::string, int> stringmap;
       
       return stringmap;
   }

... (remainder safely uses stringmap() to get at properly-initialized map object)
};
```

It seems that "static inline" objects have similar semantics to these objects-embedded-in-a-function.  Can they safely be used inside a class while avoiding the fiasco?

For example,

```
struct GlobalHashTable
{
   static inline std::map <std::string, int> stringmap;

... (remainder safely uses stringmap to get at properly-initialized map object)
};
```

Comment: "*It seems that "static inline" objects have similar semantics to these objects-embedded-in-a-function.*" - what makes you say that? Whar are those *similar semantics*?

Comment: An inline object can be referred to by multiple object files, yet is guaranteed to be initialized exactly once, and I believe that there is some sort of guard around its use to accomplish this.

Comment: A non-`inline`, `static` field is also guaranteed to be initialised exactly once and can be referred to by multiple object files. Adding `inline` adds no additional requirements for ordering.

Comment: A non-inline static must be defined in exactly one object file, where it is initialized. The ordering requirements seem very different.

Comment: What *exact* ordering requirements? Please refer to a specific section from the standard or a reference point.

Comment: I do not understand: I did not say ordering requirements were exact.  I said that a static  object is initialized in exactly one object file, which is obvious.

Comment: Being initialised in exactly one object file is not connected in any way to the order of other possible initialisations. You keep saying "seem", but I fail to see *where* do you see anything that supports your claim.

Comment: See here for discussion of guards around inline variables.  These guards do not exist with static variables. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56798437/why-do-global-inline-variables-and-static-inline-members-in-c17-need-guards

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235790/discussion-between-fureeish-and-peter-fletcher).